# Count average length of words in string

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    print()
    print("Program to calculate the average word length")
    print("You will be asked to enter a sentence")
    print("Written by Reilly Peters")
    print()


    #lets the user enter a sentence
    senstr=input("Enter a sentence: ")
    print()#for turnin


    #Repeats the the users sentence
    print()
    print("Original Sentence:",senstr)

    #splits the sentence into a list
    sen = senstr.split()
    for ch in senstr.split():
        if len(ch) > 2:
            average = sum(len(ch) for ch  in sen) / len(sen)
    print("Average word length:",average)
    print()

main()
```

I have gotten this far but still cant find a way to make the average letter count of the words not include words less than 2 characters long! Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: sum(len(ch) for ch  in sen) , gives you sum of all words in sen.

Answer (score 0):

Replace for loop with this :

```
for ch in senstr.split():
    word_count = 0
    letter_count = 0
    if len(ch) > 2:
         letter_count =  letter_count + len(ch)
         word_count = word_count + 1
    print float(letter_count) / word_count
```